# SSIS - if/else expression to turn string into number

Tags: excel, ssis, formatting, expression

I have Excel sheets where the same column can contain a value with **% formatting** and also with **decimal notation**.
To clarify: In Excel both have the same formatting but due to different Excel versions (locations) SSIS shows them like this: 
**1,3%** or **0.814260540128523**

These values come in as strings so I'm trying to figure out a way to divide the % formatted values by 100 and leave the others as is.

Initially I used:

```
(DT_R8)[F5_CONV] < 1 ? (DT_R8)[F5_CONV] : (DT_R8)[F5_CONV] / 100
```

in a **second derived column** but I then realized that **0,23%** is also a possible value.

I think something like this should do it but I'm having trouble with the DT_WSTR and DT_R8 types.

```
(F5 == "" || ISNULL(F5)) ? NULL(DT_WSTR,40) : FINDSTRING(F5,"%",1) > 0 
? (DT_WSTR,40)REPLACE(REPLACE(F5,".",","),"%","")  / 100  
: (DT_WSTR,40)REPLACE(F5,".",",")
```

Hope you can help me out here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(F5 == "" || ISNULL(F5)) ? NULL(DT_WSTR,40) : FINDSTRING(F5,"%",1) > 0 
? (DT_WSTR,40)((DT_R8)REPLACE(REPLACE(F5,".",","),"%","")  / 100)  
: (DT_WSTR,40)REPLACE(F5,".",",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use script component. Here is a quick solution; you may need to add validations for null. Let us know, if you ne[image]ed help.